# How to verify Kafka rack awareness?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Have anyone came across debugging rack-awareness feature of Apache Kafka? We are running OSS version 2.6.0 on aws, `broker.rack` value is populated during deployment, clients have their `client.rack` passed during initialization (mostly Flink and Kafka streams), but based on bill metrics, I don't see any change in bill metrics.
(Replication factor is 2 across 3 aws AZ).

Comment: That setting is only relevant for consumers, so if your producers are very active and you have a high replication factor, then there will still be cross AZ traffic you'll be paying for

Comment: Yep, I know that this is relevant only for consumers. I'd love to have a sanity check or any kind of indicator that consumers manage to consume from replica and not leader partition.
As of now, based on billing metrics "pull from closest partition" didn't work, although racks are configured on both brokers and clients.

Comment: My only thought would be packet capture on the consumers (e.g. TCPdump into Wireshark) then inspect what brokers are actually used by the consumers

Comment: thanks, but not very relevant at our scale. Also, running tcpdump inside k8s pod is a headache.

Comment: You don't need to do it inside the pod. You can do it server side then look at the incoming fetch requests to the brokers

Comment: Kafka brokers also run on pods and these clusters are heavy used, e.g. each broker gets lots of fetch request. But I'll consider this option. Thanks

Comment: One extreme option would be to setup the broker listeners on a separate port for cross broker replication than client connections, then use firewall/VPC rules to whitelist only the brokers on that port for cross AZ traffic. Then deny all other cross AZ client traffic on other port(s)